# HTML Not Displaying Correctly in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I just started in VSCode and I'm trying to make a website. I have a basic HTML code and when I run it, it displays the code that I have into a tab in Chrome instead of what the actual website would be like.[my code before running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPyaM.png)[what displays after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PczBl.png)

I tried creating a new file, uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode, and it still doesn't work.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>The Template Element</h1>
<p>Click the button below to display the hidden content from the template element.</p>
<button onclick = "showContent()"> Button</button> 
<h2>Flower</h2>
<img src = "images/Cello Wallpapers - Wallpaper Cave.jpg" width = "214" height ="204">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your actual code, not screenshots of it!

Comment: I tried to and it wouldn't let me. It says I have to put 4 spaces in front of my code and I did but it wouldn't let me post it

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Please edit my starting point in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your file with a `.html` file extension.  Otherwise, the browser doesn't really know the type of file you want it to open and treats it like text.